# How do I configure vim/emacs to run scripts?

Tags: vim, emacs

I'd like to configure both Vim and Emacs to be able to run bash scripts from within the editor, so that I can commit/push my code without having to leave the editor.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Within Vim, you can run any command using `:!`, e.g.,

```
:!ls
```

or

```
:!hg ci -m "Check-in comment"
```

See

```
:help :!
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has a shell mode that can used to open a shell.  Try <kbd>Esc</kbd>x`shell`.

However, if you want to commit code from with emacs, there are modules which allow you to work with version control from within emacs.  The installations I have worked with automatically detects files under version control.  Version control shows up in the file status line.

Answer (score 1):

The `:!` command is as old as venerable vi; to speed up the repeated application (beyond `:!!`), either set up custom mappings (`:nnoremap ...`), or use a plugin like [vcscommand.vim - CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=90), which provides a lot of VCS-related functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of some bash scripts you can use some scripts for Vim or Emacs that run as wrappers around Git, so you can use git commands without leaving the editor.

A great Git plugin for Vim is [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), some Emacs Git plugins are listed [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Git).

If you're using both editors you can remap the keys of the Git commands to be consistent.